# Redis failover triggers slow response times on some IIS instances

Tags: windows, iis, redis, centos

We have 4 instances of IIS running. The .NET web app persists data to SQL Server HA and uses Redis for session store. All of these are hosted on servers in a single data center.

Redis, Redis-Sentinel and HAProxy are running as containers on 4 CentOS instances in a HA config.

The web app is using the Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider 4.0.1 provider. The connection string in web.config is as follows:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="SessionStateStore" timeout="50">
  <providers>
    <add name="SessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" connectionString="10.40.50.50:26379,10.40.50.51:26379,10.40.50.52:26379,10.40.50.53:26379,ssl=false,password=aPassword,serviceName=master" throwOnError="False" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Since going into production a couple of weeks ago, I've noticed some IIS instances report significantly slower response times immediately after a Redis failover, probably once every few days. Sometimes 2 out  of the 4 web servers are slow after Redis fails over, and the app pools need restarting. Other times, it may be just the 1. On other occasions, all 4 IIS servers report slow response but correct themselves after a few minutes without needing to restart the app pool.

Is there a way to determine why Redis is failing over? Also, what's a good approach to troubleshoot the IIS side to identify if certain active requests at the time of the failover results in a higher thread count, therefore slower response?

Comment: `Is there a way to determine why Redis is failing over?` Can you provide sentinel logs?

Comment: @usuario Yes, I can. Does it matter which Sentinel instance the logs are provided from? Thanks.

Comment: sentinels monitoring the failovered masters